Black screen when connecting my second monitor
I have Ubuntu 24.04 installed. On the nVidia 550 driver, I get a black screen on boot on both monitors when I have both monitors connected. When I only have one monitor connected, the system runs fine. As soon as the second is connected, both screens are black.
The following kernel message is printed whenever I connect the second monitor:
drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

So far I was able to work around this issue by installing version 535 of the nVidia driver. However, this is not a permanent solution, as 535 does not work with Ghost of Tsushima.

The issue was resolved when disabling "Adaptive Sync", which was a setting on my monitors. When this feature is enabled, the screen goes black. When disabled, the screen works normally
